# How to synchronize files in a bucket with aws sdk php

Tags: php, aws-sdk

From the cli, I use a command like this `/usr/bin/aws s3 sync $LOCALPATH $REMOTEPATH --metadata-directive REPLACE --cache-control max-age=$TTL`

Is there a similar command in the aws sdk php that will upload the contents of a local directory AND delete the files in the bucket that aren't present in the local directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no similar command in the AWS SDK for PHP that will upload the contents of a local directory AND delete the files in the bucket that aren't present in the local directory.